# Save a file as the previous weekday's date

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, dateadd, weekday

I need to save a file as the previous weekday's date. On Mondays, I need to save the file as Friday's date.

Here's what I have:

```
If FileDate = Weekday(Date, vbMonday) Then Format(DateAdd("d", -3, Date)) = "yyyymmdd" Else FileDate = Format(DateAdd("d", -1, Date), "yyyymmdd")
```

This is spitting out date-1 even on Mondays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it a try like this. It will print the correct name of the file:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim fileDate    As String

    If Weekday(Date, vbMonday) = 1 Then
        fileDate = Format(DateAdd("d", -3, Date), "yyyymmdd")
    Else
        fileDate = Format(DateAdd("d", -1, Date), "yyyymmdd")
    End If

    Debug.Print fileDate

End Sub
```

Comment: This will not work in all conditions. Depending on what date settings you have, Mondays are sometimes the first day of the week, sometimes the second.

Comment: @sam - can you try to change your own PC, setting Monday as a second day of the week and then trying to run the code and tell me what you get?

Comment: Try running the Weekday function with various values in the second argument.

Comment: @sam - why should I change `vbMonday` to something else? It forces VBA to think that Monday is the first day of my week.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: It was pointed out that I made a mistake with the Weekday function structure.  Added the "= 1" to the initial if condition.

Good morning kms5549. Just tested this and it seems to spit out the correct day. Hope this helps,

```
Dim fileDate As String

If Weekday(Date, vbMonday) = 1 Then
    fileDate = Format(DateAdd("d", -3, Date), "yyyymmdd")
Else
    fileDate = Format(DateAdd("d", -1, Date), "yyyymmdd")
End If
```

Comment: @Vityata - You're absolutely correct, my apologies. 
I misunderstood the equations structure... silly me. 

Well now I learned. Weekday(Date, "The first day of the week")  and it returns the #of the day. i.e. if you start the week on monday - using vbMonday, then it'll return 1 for Mondays, 2 for Tues, and so forth.

Comment: @Vityata Edited, Thanks.